# Transferring data from one table to another, some relational columns

Tags: mysql, insert

**Table 1** - this table is completely populated from an XLSX file...

[image]

**Tables 2 and 3** - contain 1-1 references for a couple of the columns in the final table.

[image]

**Table 3** - the on I am trying to get populated with first three tables....

[image]

As you can see, the tables are sensible, there is no einsteinic equations or conversions going on. Here is the code that I have already tried, unsuccessfully:

```
INSERT INTO att_oem_orders SELECT NULL, ost.om_or_po, (SELECT j.job_id FROM jobs j WHERE j.project_number = project_no), NULL, (SELECT ao.id FROM att_oem WHERE ao.item_no = item_no), ost.po_number, (SELECT ol.id FROM order_lsc WHERE STATUS = ol.line_status_code), ost.ordered_date, ost.shipment_date, NULL, NULL, ost.item_qty, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ost.shipping_to, ost.tracking_number, ost.carrier) FROM oem_temp_sync WHERE ost.item_qty > 0
```

Comment: Did you try to explicitly list the columns in att_oem_orders that you want to Insert Into? (I assume the Select statement works)

Comment: The `SELECT` statement is crazy. it asks for table names where some fields are redundant and it gives me `Sub-query returns more than 1 row` in several of the sub-queries. Maybe I need to do this programatically, because the SQL is turning my brain to sauce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting the number of possible values to put into a field using FIRST() like so:

```
INSERT INTO att_oem_orders SELECT
    NULL,
    ost.om_or_po,
    (SELECT FIRST(j.job_id) FROM jobs j WHERE j.project_number = project_no),
    NULL,
    (SELECT FIRST(ao.id) FROM att_oem WHERE ao.item_no = item_no),
    ost.po_number,
    (SELECT FIRST(ol.id) FROM order_lsc WHERE STATUS = ol.line_status_code),
    ost.ordered_date,
    ost.shipment_date,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ost.item_qty,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ost.shipping_to,
    ost.tracking_number,
    ost.carrier
FROM oem_temp_sync WHERE ost.item_qty > 0
```

You also appear to have an extra ) just before FROM

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of help from everyone, I've found a few errors and fixed a few sub-queries. Here is the final version:

```
INSERT INTO att_oem_orders 
SELECT 
    NULL,
    ost.om_or_po,
    (SELECT 
        FIRST(j.id) 
    FROM
        jobs j 
    WHERE j.project_number = ost.project_no),
    NULL,
    (SELECT 
        FIRST(ao.id) 
    FROM
        att_oem ao
    WHERE ao.item_no = ost.item_no),
    ost.po_number,
    (SELECT 
        FIRST(ol.id) 
    FROM
        att_oem_lsc ol
    WHERE ol.status = ost.line_status_code),
    ost.ordered_date,
    ost.shipment_date,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ost.item_qty,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ost.ship_to,
    ost.tracking_no,
    ost.carrier
FROM
    oem_sync_temp  ost
WHERE ost.item_qty > 0
```